# How to set Delay for loop in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler

I am trying to display a multiplication table with delay. My code is working fine but I am not able to implement the delay.

Here is My code:

```
tableButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
tableButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {       
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                    str = tableButton1.getText().toString();  
                     a = Integer.parseInt(str);
                     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                     for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
                        sb.append(a + " x " + i + " = " + i * a+ "\n");

                     }
                     s = String.valueOf(sb);

                    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TextViewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("MA", s);
                    startActivity(intent);
             }
         });
         //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi"  +ss, 222).show();              
    }       
});
```

Any answer is appreciable.

Thank's in advance

**Updated-code**:- This code is working with help of @theLittleNaruto

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TestActivity  extends Activity{
Button tableButton1;
TextView txtView; 

int value = 0; 
    static int count = 0;
    Handler handle = new Handler();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    Runnable r  = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onrunnable" +sb, 222).show();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            updateTable();
        }
    };

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.text_display);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "oncreate" , 222).show();
                txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputTXT);
               tableButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
               tableButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {       

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onclick" , 222).show();
                value= Integer.parseInt(tableButton1.getText().toString()); 
                updateTable();

            }
       });
      }


     public void updateTable(){

        count+=1000;
        if(count==11000){
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onupdate" , 222).show();
            count = 0;
            value=0;
            handle.removeCallbacks(r);
            sb.setLength(0);

        }else{

            sb.append(value + " x " + count/1000 + " = " + count/1000 * value+ "\n");
                        handle.postDelayed(r, 1000);
                       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onupdateElse" +sb, 222).show();
                        txtView.setText(sb);
        }


    }


}
```

Thank you all the supporters and their best try to help me

Comment: Do you want a delay between the multiplications or before multiplications start?

Comment: I wanted to delay between the multiplication..

Comment: Then you can use a Timer as in some of the answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why dont you try what the other is saying with this little effort ;)

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity{

int value = 0; 
    static int count = 0;
    Handler handle = new Handler();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    Runnable r  = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            updateTable();
        }
    };

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.oaot_get);


               tableButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {       


                value= Integer.parseInt(tableButton1.getText().toString()); 
                updateTable();

            }
       });
      }


     public void updateTable(){

        count+=1000;
        if(count==11000){

            count = 0;
            value=0;
            handle.removeCallbacks(r);
            sb.setLength(0);

        }else{

            sb.append(value + " x " + count/1000 + " = " + count/1000 * value+ "\n");
                        handle.postDelayed(r, 1000);

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: I need some extra help to solve this problem how to get delay between numbers.

Comment: You can do it on your own. Just be calm and think. This is simple dude

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        str = tableButton1.getText().toString();  
        a = Integer.parseInt(str);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
            sb.append(a + " x " + i + " = " + i * a+ "\n");
        }
    }, 5000);
s = String.valueOf(sb);

Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TextViewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("MA", s);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a handler(). Replace your onClick code with:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 str = tableButton1.getText().toString();  
                        a = Integer.parseInt(str);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
                        {
                            sb.append(a + " x " + i + " = " + i * a+ "\n");

                        }s=String.valueOf(sb);


                        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TextViewActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("MA", s);
                        startActivity(intent);
                     }
    }, 5000);
```

Repalce 5000 with the time you want it to be delayed for in milliseconds

Comment: Welcome!!i tried it working fine but i wanted to delay inside my multiplication table.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `Handler` that will execute your runnable:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        str = tableButton1.getText().toString();  
        a = Integer.parseInt(str);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
            sb.append(a + " x " + i + " = " + i * a+ "\n");
//--ADDED stuff here------------------------------------------------------------
            try {
               //Sleep will suspend your Thread for 500 miliseconds and resumes afterwards
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e("error, Thread interrupted", e);
            }
        }
        s = String.valueOf(sb);

        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TextViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("MA", s);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
Handler handler = new Handler();
//this will execute your runnable after 500 milliseconds
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);
```

Comment: Welcome!!i tried it before but i am able to delay at the starting of my table but i wanted to delay inside my multiplication table.

Comment: @Chandan : I added an edit in the code to delay every step in the loop.

Comment: i tried to implement on my click button but as i use this line handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500); it start giving me error..all line is red.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that :

```
public class Scheduler {

// DATA
private OnScheduleTimeListener  mListener;
private Handler                 mHandler;
private int                     mInterval;          // Between each executions
private static final int        DELAY   = 100;      // before first execution
private boolean                 mIsTimerRunning;

public static interface OnScheduleTimeListener {

    public void onScheduleTime();
}

public Scheduler(int interval) {
    super();
    mInterval = interval;
    mHandler = new Handler();
}

private final Runnable  mRunnable   = new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            // Do stuff
                                            mListener.onScheduleTime();
                                            // Repeat
                                            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, mInterval);
                                        }
                                    };

public void setOnScheduleTimeListener(OnScheduleTimeListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public void startTimer() {
    mIsTimerRunning = true;
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, DELAY);
}

public void stopTimer() {
    mIsTimerRunning = false;
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
}

public boolean isTimerRunning() {
    return mIsTimerRunning;
}
}
```

Now to use it :

```
private void startTimer() {
        mScheduler = new Scheduler(INTERVAL);
        mScheduler.setOnScheduleTimeListener(new OnScheduleTimeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScheduleTime() {
                Log.d(TAG, "update");
        });
        mScheduler.startTimer();
}

private void stopTimer(){
    if (mScheduler != null && mScheduler.isTimerRunning()) {
        mScheduler.stopTimer();
        mScheduler = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a simple solution only using postDelayed which does not freeze the thread. I use it for small ui updates like every 30sec (delay and times are all in milliseconds)

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
    do {
        try {
            try {
                response_req_sequence = SimpleHttpClient
                        .sendresponseSequReqRes(response_send_order);
                System.out.println("response of sequence request"
                        + response_req_sequence);
                System.out.println(" i  ma in thread");
                if (response_req_sequence.trim().length() != 0) {
                    System.out.println("response in result of sequ"+ response_req_sequence);
                    break;
                }
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    } while (response_req_sequence.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""));
```

This is working fine for me. you can customize according to you.