# how to break an array string text in android?

Tags: android, arrays

Greeting!!
 I wanted to display table like this:-

- 1 * 1 = 1
- 1 * 2 = 2
-   -
- 
- 1 * 10 = 10

  But i am able to display 1st line then it disappear then it show next line . i am trying with string array to display the number.

**Here is my code:-**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView txtView; 
    static String test[]={"","1","","1 *","","1 * 1","","1 * 1 = 1",
        "","1","","1 *","","1 * 2","","1 * 2 = 2",
        "","1","","1 *","","1 * 3","","1 * 3 = 3",
        "","1","","1 *","","1 * 4","","1 * 4 = 4",
        "","1","","1 *","","1 * 5","","1 * 5 = 5",
        "","1","","1 *","","1 * 6","","1 * 6 = 6",
        "","1","","1 *","","1 * 7","","1 * 7 = 7",
        "","1","","1 *","","1 * 8","","1 * 8 = 8",
        "","1","","1 *","","1 * 9","","1 * 9 = 9",
        "","1","","1 *","","1 * 10","","1 * 10 = 10"};
    Handler handler;
    ImageView imageView;
    Runnable runnable;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent i = getIntent(); 
        String someVariable = i.getStringExtra("MA");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SomeVariable" +someVariable, 222).show();

        txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greentxt_name);



     handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {

      int t=0;
      public void run() {

          sb.append(test[t]);

          t++;

          if( t>=79)
          { 


           handler.removeCallbacks(runnable) ;
           txtView.setText(test[t]);

          }
          else
          { txtView.setText(test[t]);
          handler.postDelayed(this,1000);    
          }
      }
  };
  handler.postDelayed(runnable, -1000); //for initial delay..
}


}
```

Any answer is appreciable.

Thank's in advance

Comment: looks like you might want to use a listview, while each of the listviews views has a tablelayout. But you will habe to write a customAdapter for that purpose.

Comment: Welcome!! i wanted to display table one by one number so that i coded like this.but i don't understand how to appear whole table once.

Comment: txtView.append(test[t]);
instead of
txtView.setText(test[t]);
hope i got you right.

Comment: also using a loop to print this table would have been easier than writing this big string array.

Comment: @user2469133 it displaying the whole array but i wanted to display 1 * 1 = 1 |1 * 2 = 2 |1 * 3 =3...|1 * 10 = 10

Comment: @user2469133 yeah i used with loop [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328355/how-to-set-delay-for-loop-in-android) but it showing line by line but i wanted number by number that's why i used this process but it only showing single line..:(

Comment: if you want them displayed one by one, just set a delay on every view the getView method creates/populates

Comment: @DanielBo sorry i didn't get your words.can u help me with some code i am thankful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited your code a bit to achieve the desired result
Here it goes :

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView txtView; 
    static String test[]={"1"," * ","1"," = ","1", "\n",
        "1"," * ","2"," = ","2", "\n",
        "1"," * ","3"," = ","3", "\n",
        "1"," * ","4"," = ","4", "\n",
        "1"," * ","5"," = ","5", "\n",
        "1"," * ","6"," = ","6", "\n",
        "1"," * ","7"," = ","7", "\n",
        "1"," * ","8"," = ","8", "\n",
        "1"," * ","9"," = ","9", "\n",
        "1"," * ","10"," = ","10"};

    Handler handler;
    ImageView imageView;
    Runnable runnable;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent i = getIntent(); 
        txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greentxt_name);



     handler = new Handler();
     runnable = new Runnable() {

      int t=0;
      public void run() {

          sb.append(test[t]);

          t++;

          if( t>=59)
          { 


           handler.removeCallbacks(runnable) ;
           txtView.setText(sb);

          }
          else
          { txtView.setText(sb);
          handler.postDelayed(this,1000);    
          }

        }};
     handler.postDelayed(runnable, -1000); //for initial delay.. 
}}
```

You can remove the hard-coded values and generalize it so that it can be used for any other table in future.

Comment: welcome it worked but still i have same problem .it display in single line but i wanted 1 after that second line

Comment: Great!! it worked for me as for my requirement.i wanted to add voice on this letter can you help me how to do that.

Comment: i want some little help..i was trying with get on click of button earlier but its directly view my first table can u help how to get on particular button click in different activity.i am grateful to you.

Comment: I didn't get you. Is it related to this question? If not, please create another question.

Comment: Greeting for reply!!!i am trying to call this table on a button 1 (http://pastie.org/8682066 ) to display in another page(http://pastie.org/8682062). but when i click on the button it start the table one automatically.

Comment: It is going to show up immediately after the Activity comes up. The table code is written in the onCreate method of the Activity.

Comment: Yeah!!but my requirement is to start TExtActivity on particular number comes from the tableNumber in MainActivity.

Comment: I still dont get you question. Is it that you want to send a number from TextActivity and show the respective table for that number in the MainActivity?

Comment: yeah!!when i click button number 1 on first xml then it display table in second xml

Comment: If you send number 2, it is still going to show you the table of 1 as the code is not generic. I had mentioned this in the answer previously.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this. :

```
StringBuffer str= new StringBuffer();
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
    str.append(""+1+" * "+i+" = "+(1*i)+"\n");
    Log.e("", ""+str.toString());
}
txt.setText(str);
```

Comment: welcome !! i tried with this method but i wanted to get entry from the button clicked. i tried  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328355/how-to-set-delay-for-loop-in-android) but i am not able to display number by number.

Answer (score 0):

The text in the textview keeps getting replaced because of the new index value that comes up from text[t]

You can change the logic a bit by Concatenating the row as next line in the sb string and replace

```
txtView.setText(test[t]);
```

by

```
txtView.setText(sb);
```

Comment: i tried the both but it doesn't work for me .it show all the content .i used to display the number by number that's why i used text[t].so i am able to display number by number here.

Comment: Make use of another string that keeps track of your row (in your case 8 index values each time)and once done, add a new line to it. Also, keep adding this text to sb